# Testinfra ssh execution with private key

Tags: python, ssh, tdd, pytest, private-key

Using testinfra (Pytest plugin) for testing. I want to test remote hosts from Jenkins using a private key.

```
[root@jenkins tests]# testinfra --ssh-config=/path/to/private/key \
     --sudo --hosts=user@remotehost test.py
```

where

```
$ cat /path/to/private/key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
(...)
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and

```
$ cat test.py
def test_redis_is_installed(host):
    redis = host.package("redis")
    assert redis.is_installed
```

What I get is

```
E               Exception: Unparsable line -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/config.py:68: Exception
================================================================================= warnings summary ==================================================================================
None
  Module already imported so can not be re-written: testinfra

-- Docs: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
======================================================================= 1 failed, 1 warnings in 0.23 seconds ========================================================================
```

Seems like paramiko doesn't like this format, but tried other backends and it doesn't work as well. How can I pass the private key then?

Comment: did you manage to make it work with --ssh-identity-file?

Answer (score 1):

`--ssh-config` must be a path to ssh **config**. You configure keypair for the host in that config.

Something like in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host remotehost
    User user
    IdentityFile remotehost-key
```

Comment: is it possible to make it work with --ssh-identity-file? Can you maybe check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76581673/execute-testinfra-ssh-using-ssh-identity-file-directly